# Branch coverage with missing else

Tags: testing, branch, code-coverage

Given some code:

```
int(x) {
 if(x==0) { dosomething }
}
```

If I run this with two test cases: t1 = <0> and t2 = <2>, will this provide me with 100% branch coverage even though the else statement is missing?

In other words, does the else statement need to exist to achieve 100% branch coverage?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, these two inputs will result in full branch coverage. `else` is not required for full branch coverage.

You may consider that there's an empty implicit `else` block.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Wouldn't two test cases suffice, t1=<x=0,y=0> and t2=<x!=0,y==0>? As this would cause both branches to be executed no?

Doesn't the above example border onto condition/multi-condition testing?

Comment: I say this as I am referring to the book "Software Testing and Analysis" by Mauro where I read the following definition for condition testing: "Branch coverage is useful for exercising faults in the way a computation has been decomposed into cases. Condition coverage considers this decomposition in more detail, forcing exploration not only of both possible results of a Boolean expression controlling a branch, but also of different combinations of the individual conditions in a compound Boolean expression."

Comment: You're right, that's condition coverage according to this definition. Modified the answer.